# 'Export to Spreadsheet' error

Tags: wss-3.0, excel, office-integration

I'm working with WSS 3.0 and have access to a number of sites within SharePoint.

I and a number of other users have run into an issue that is happening when we try export a list using the "Export to Spreadsheet" option.

The export creates a .iqy file which is then opened in Excel 2007. Once Excel opens, there is a prompt to enable the data connection. I click "Enable".

Excel then tries to connect to the site but hangs in the end and cannot open the file.

How to solve this issue?

Please help!

-saumil

ps --- My System is Office 2007, Windows 7, WSS 3.0 & IE 8.0

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some proxy restriction s in your environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this same issue. For me it was caused by authentication not working correctly between the browser and office.
When you get the hang, see if you can minimise the window, then redisplay it. 
Usually there is a authentication box hiding somewhere.

First, im going to assume this is an intranet?

Close all your browsers, when you go to the sharepoint site, does it ask you for a username and password?

If it does, you need to correct that by setting up your browser zones. 
IE -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Security. 
Make sure the site is in local intranet (trusted sites might work too)

Close the browser and try again, you should be automatically logged on.

If that doesn't work, then are are more methods you can try

http://www.portalsolutions.net/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=27

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280/en-us

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run into this issue myself, but you could look at OfficeWriter from SoftArtisans. It can export a SharePoint list to an Excel file, but by default doesn't maintain any sort of data connection back to SharePoint. It's a lot more flexible than the SharePoint "Export to Excel" function... you can have custom Excel templates that let you brand the exported list. You can also use other Excel features (like formulas, charts, conditional formatting, etc.). There's information about it on their site at http://officewriter.softartisans.com/officewriter-434.aspx.

---

Full Disclosure - I work for SoftArtisans.

Comment: Thanks Chaulky!! Was looking for a free option!! Anyways, thanks for your help!1